# How to separate a branch into feature branches

Tags: git

I have a codebase that didn't use git so far. I've made a new branch and did some cleaning. The last three commits are:

```
bdd0f42ca51734a10a09985fa65abb81c876432d deleted Feature 2
ef236bb88de9aa4e4839b52b7a5131e437174d48 deleted Feature 1 <-- Feature 2 is still in it
db3be0c46e7e5abc3f234a675424cd92f0dcd78e deleted Garbage <-- Feature 1 and Feature 2 is still in it
```

The current head is the desired starting point for further development, i.e. the initial state of release, develop and master.

How can I save Feature 1 and Feature 2 into two separate feature branches, that can be merged later as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might consider this:

```
git checkout -b feature/2 # create feature/2 branch
git revert bdd0f42
```

the `git revert` will create the inverse commit of commit `bdd0f42`
hence adding feature 2 again

then for feature 1:

```
git checkout -b feature/1 bdd0f42 # create feature/1 branch from your HEAD commit
git revert ef236bb
```

this might be a little more tricky; since code changes between feature1 and feature2 might affect the same files...

Comment: That did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume by saying "deleted Feature X" you mean you reverted the code with that feature.
Further, as you have reverted these features you should also be having commits having the code for the features. So your commits would look like (reverse chronological) :

```
(a4s5s2) * deleted Feature 2
         |
(d2r3t4) * deleted Feature 1
         |
(fd32d3) * deleted Garbage
         |
(dt3d23) * added Feature 2
         |
(dw24d1) * added Feature 1
         |
(23d234) * other commits..
```

Where the alphanumerical values written in parenthesis are the last parts of the commit ids.

Now coming on to the **solution** for your problem :

- Go to commit `(dw24d1) * added Feature 1` by using command `git checkout dw24d1` then create a new branch from this commit using command `git checkout -b feature1`
- Similarly, go to your main branch using command `git checkout main-branch`, go to commit `(dt3d23) * added Feature 1` by using command `git checkout dt3d23` then create a new branch from this commit using command `git checkout -b feature2`
- Finally to come back to your latest commit on your main branch using command `git checkout main-branch`

After doing all this what you will achieve is 3 branches - main-branch (containing latest code), feature1 (containing feature 1), feature2 (containing feature 2).

---

Edit:

As you mentioned, you do not have the commits for the features added.
In this case, you can simply do the following : (considering you are at latest commit of your main branch, say `master`)

- Create new branch for feature 1 using command `git checkout -b feature1`, then commit feature 1 code on this branch
- Go back to master branch using command `git checkout master`, then create new branch for feature 2 using command `git checkout -b feature2`, then commit feature 2 code on this branch
- Go back to master branch using command `git checkout master` and continue work.

Comment: There are no previous commits adding the features. The codebase was just a bunch of files.

Comment: In that case, you will need to make branches from your latest commit now, and then add a commit to feature branches with the required feature code.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a `new_release` branch with having last 3 commits

1. feature 1
2. feature 2
3. feature 3.

Now, you have created a new branch (`feature_1`) from `dev`.

you can simply `cherry-pick` feature1 commit by `commit Id`.

In `feature_1` branch you can do,

```
 git cherry-pick {commitIdOfFeature1}
```

After that, your feature_1 will have all commits of dev and the commit you have given id.

In this way, you can create different branches for your different requirement.